# What is a good way of testing an exception raised from a decorator?

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, testing, python-decorators

In a module which defines a decorator 'foo', what is a good way to test exceptions that foo is supposed to throw? I'm looking for a simple test that can go at the end of a module, like so:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    @foo
    def bar(quux):
        pass

    #test that foo raises a particular exception when decorating bar
```

I'm guessing I could make an expect_exception decorator to decorate the foo-decorated bar function. Is there a better way? Maybe the easiest way is to apply the decorator 'manually'?:

```
    try:
        bar = foo(bar)
    except FooException:
        # test passed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorating it "manually" as you describe will work.  You can also just do the decoration normally inside a function or try/except:

```
try:
    @foo
    def bar(quux):
        pass
except FooException:
    # test passed
```